# React Native android bundling with dev bundle instead of staging

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project that works fine if I am running the dev/debug version of the app
I have created a staging build type for android added this to the `build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
        bundleInStaging: true,
        enableHermes   : false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
        devDisabledInStaging: true,
]
```

It still fires off metro if it's not running but also bundles the JS to the expected folder however when I run the app I get an error where it cannot find the

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.`

Let me know if you need anymore information from me

React Native version `0.70.5`

Tried to do a clean and build, restarted computer and cleaned emulators but still the same also happens in the pipelines

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to figure out the reason? @saied-nawaz

Comment: Yes, first make sure you are using the latest version of react native.
Make sure you are using the correct flavour so it might be flavorDebug and I am not 100% sure you might need to make that flavour debuggable too